# Projecting simultaneous database queries

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, capacity-planning

I’m after some thoughts on how people go about calculating database load for the purposes of capacity planning. I haven’t put this on Server Fault because the question is related to measuring just the application rather than defining the infrastructure. In this case, it’s someone else’s job to worry about that bit!

I’m aware there are a huge number of variables here but I’m interested in how others go about getting a sense of rough order of magnitude. This is simply a costing exercise early in a project lifecycle before any specific design has been created so not a lot of info to go on at this stage.

The question I’ve had put forward from the infrastructure folks is “how many simultaneous users”. Let’s not debate the rationale of seeking only this one figure; it’s just what’s been asked for in this case!

This is a web front end, SQL Server backend with a fairly fixed, easily quantifiable audience. To nail this down to actual simultaneous requests in a very rough fashion, the way I see it, it comes down to increasingly granular units of measurement:

1. Total audience
2. Simultaneous sessions
3. Simultaneous requests
4. Simultaneous DB queries

This doesn’t account for factors such as web app caching, partial page requests, record volume etc and there’s some creative license needed to define frequency of requests per user and number of DB hits and execution time but it seems like a reasonable starting point. I’m also conscious of the need to scale for peak load but that’s something else that can be plugged into the simultaneous sessions if required.

This is admittedly very basic and I’m sure there’s more comprehensive guidance out there. If anyone can share their approach to this exercise or point me towards other resources that might make the process a little less ad hoc, that would be great!

Comment: Is it a completely new application or do you have an older equivalent/baseline? Is this application accessible from the internet or is it for internal use only?

Comment: All new, internal only so everything is a projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try, but obviously without knowing the details it is quite difficult to give a precise advice.

First of all, the infrastructure guys might have asked this question from the licensing perspective (SQL server can be licensed per user or per CPU)

Now back to your question. "Total audience" is important if you can predict/work out this number. This can give you the worst case scenario when all users hit the database at once (e.g. 9am when everyone logs in).

If you store session information you would probably have at least 2 connections per user (1 session + 1 main DB). But this number can be (sometimes noticeably) reduced by connection pooling (depends on how you connect to the database).
Use a worst case scenario - 50 system connection + 2 * number of users.

Simultaneous requests/queries depend on the nature of the application. Need more details.
More simultaneous requests (to your front end) will not necessarily translate to more requests on the back end.

Having said all of that - for the costing purposes you need to focus on a bigger picture.

1. SQL server license (If my memory serves me right) will cost ~128K AUD (dual Xeon). Hot/warm standby? Double the cost.
2. Disk storage - how much storage will you need? Disks are relatively cheap but if you are going to use SAN the cost might become noticeable. Also - the more disks the better from the performance perspective.